# Datepicker CSS changing colors of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to change the colour of the selected dates in jQuery Datepicker using  in CSS with *!important*.

beforeShowDay invokes a function (f1) checking if days are present in arrays (t1, t2 and t3) and if the same day is present in two different arrays (10-6-2016 in this case) the latter occurence is omitted.

I would like it to be the reverse: if a day is found again in an array the color already set should be changed to a new color. Can anyone help?

### jQuery

```
function f1(date){
    t1=[ '10-6-2016','11-6-2016'];
    t2=['15-6-2016', '16-6-2016'];
    t3=['10-6-2016','20-6-2016','21-6-2016'];
    dmy=date.getDate() + "-" +(date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if($.inArray(dmy,t1) !==-1){return[true,'tt1','selectable'];} // check for date
    if($.inArray(dmy,t3) !==-1){return[true,'tt3','selectable'];} // check for datey
    if($.inArray(dmy,t2) !==-1){return[false,'tt2','unselectable'];} // check for date
    else{return[true,"","selectable"];}
}
```

### CSS

```
.tt1  a{
    background-image:none !important;
    background:red !important;
    color:#fff !important;
    opacity:100 !important;

}
.tt2 span{
    background:blue !important ;
    color:#fff !important;
    opacity:100 !important; 
}
.tt3  a{
    background-image:none !important;
    background:green!important;
    color:#fff !important;
    opacity:100 !important;
```

Comment: to override the defaults

Comment: But wat about not loading the default an create your own style? That's how I do it myself and creates way nicer css

Answer (score 0):

Because of `return`, your function returns an `array` on the first `if` condition meet.
It also halts the function.

**EDIT:**

Check you console logs with this:

```
function f1(date){
    t1=['10-6-2016','11-6-2016'];
    t2=['15-6-2016','16-6-2016'];
    t3=['10-6-2016','20-6-2016','21-6-2016'];
    dmy=date.getDate() + "-" +(date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

    presentInt1=false;
    presentInt2=false;
    presentInt3=false;

    if($.inArray(dmy,t1) !==-1){            // Test servers's date + 1 month against array t1
        console.log("Date is in array t1.");
        presentInt1=true;
    }

    if($.inArray(dmy,t2) !==-1){            // Test servers's date + 1 month against array t2
        console.log("Date is in array t2.");
        presentInt2=true;
    }

    if($.inArray(dmy,t3) !==-1){            // Test servers's date + 1 month against array t3
        console.log("Date is in array t3.");
        presentInt3=true;
    }

    // Than here, use those `presentIn` boolean true/false variables to make a choice.
    // I don't know... ;)
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not work, even with the answer/anwser typo corrected; only the last  t2 array shows, but thanks for the input.

Comment: Sorry for the typo... I edited something your could try. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your comment (L. P. Bessette) steered me the right way. Datepicker checks for every day and returns when it finds a match; in this case in array ***t1*** it finds 10-6-2016 and then returns with true and the corresponding CSS; it never reaches **t3** when it checks for 10-6-2016. So I could move the if-t3 to **before** if-t1 or write some more convoluted if statements. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Hew... Well, then accept my answer (green check) instead of posting another answer to reply to me. ;) Glad I helped.